# Celery "chain" task in time

Tags: python, celery

I have a task that can be only executed once at time
I have try something based on this [link](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html) and this [link](http://loose-bits.com/2010/10/distributed-task-locking-in-celery.html)

```
@contextmanager
def redis_lock(task_name):
    lock = REDIS_CLIENT.lock("lock-{}".format(task_name))
    status = False
    try:
        status = lock.acquire(blocking)
        yield status
    finally:
        if status:
            lock.release()
```

However with that solution if I have only 2 processes, all the processes will be blocked and if I have another task it will wait aswell. Futhermore I'm not sure that the tasks will be executed in the same order.

I have tried a bunch of other solution but what I'm looking is basically to get the last task of a type and then something as (not working)

```
def another_function(task_uuid):
    task = app.Task(task_uuid)
    task.link = my_task.s()

if __name__ == "__main__":
       task1 = my_task.delay()
       task_uuid = task1.id
       another_function(task_uuid)
```

And all the task will be executed in this order.
As if i'm calling the `link` method of an `AsyncResult`

Thanks for your help

edit:
Maybe I can create speciale queues by task but I can't find a way in the documentation to limit the number of process for a given queue

Comment: Why standard [chain](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains) is not enough in this situation? I heard they changed task format, so now you can have unlimited number of tasks in one chain.

Comment: Because I might need to add a task to the "chain" after a while.
And I only have the uuid avec the running task so the only thing that I am able to get is a AsyncResult